# NSString to NSNumber ignores initial zeros

Tags: ios, core-data, nsstring, nsnumber

I am converting `NSString` to `NSNumber`. But the problem is that if `NSString` starts with zeros then converting it to `NSNumber` ignores the initial zeros. I know initial zeros doesn't mean anything but I want to keep initial zeros because it's phonenumber in my case.

here is my code:

```
NSLog(@"test1: %@",tempPhoneNumber);
NSNumberFormatter *formatter=[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *tempPnoneNumberNumber=[formatter numberFromString:tempPhoneNumber];
NSLog(@"test: %@",tempPnoneNumberNumber);
```

if test1: 00966123456789
then test: 966123456789

I want both same

Comment: I don't think you can save number with leading zeros..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSNumber` cannot keep initial zeros.

If you want to keep the zeros, **don't convert it** to `NSNumber`. Phone numbers are not actually numbers, there are usually kept as strings.

Also note that phonenumbers can contain other characters: `+`, `*` or `#`. These characters often have special meaning (e.g. `+` at the beginning means the same as `00`).

Answer (score 2):

If you know how many digits a number must have, you can format it to the required number of digits with optional leading zeros by using the `"%014lli"` format. The magic number 14 is the required number of digits, including the leading zeros. Here is a link to a [demo in C](http://ideone.com/MEFDRi) that uses a `long long` constant to represent your number.

P.S. Phone numbers are not really "numbers", they are strings that happen to be composed of digits. You should not attempt converting them to numbers precisely because of the leading zeros issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not doing calculations with it then it's a string, not a number.

This applies to phone numbers, zip codes, etc.

If you do manage to store leading zeros then someone will eventually come along with this phone number: +44 (0)1234 567890 - how will you deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can accomplish this:
first, if your phone number is of fixed size then you can use this

```
NSLog(@"test %014d", tempPnoneNumberNumber);
```

else just add leading zeros by

```
[formatter setPaddingCharacter:@"00"];
```