# Int64 don't show 0 when I save on Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, int64

this is my add button:

```
guard let name = texfiedldName.text else { return }
guard let phoneNumber = texfiedldAge.text else { return }
guard let email = texfiedldEmail.text else { return }
```

formatting text

```
let scanner = Scanner(string: phoneNumber)
let validCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
let startCharacters = validCharacters.union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+#"))
var digits: NSString?
var validNumber = ""
while !scanner.isAtEnd {
    if scanner.scanLocation == 0 {
        scanner.scanCharacters(from: startCharacters, into: &digits)
    } else {
        scanner.scanCharacters(from: validCharacters, into: &digits)
    }
    scanner.scanUpToCharacters(from: validCharacters, into: nil)
    if let digits = digits as String? {
        validNumber.append(digits)
    }
}
print(validNumber)
```

add to Core Data

```
let person = Person(context: PersistenceService.context)
person.name = name
person.number = Int64(validNumber)!
person.email = email
PersistenceService.saveContext()
self.people.append(person)
```

this is my output

```
085293173
```

but in the tableViewCell

```
85293173
```

can you help me please?

Comment: Integer values never have leading zeros

Comment: check this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25566581/leading-zeros-for-int-in-swift

Comment: @vadian and why I put in another position return me the correct number in my cell? 3200582527

Comment: Don't use integers to store phone numbers.

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743156/nsstring-to-nsnumber-ignores-initial-zeros.

Comment: @Martin R but I want it in Swift... my entity is in Int64... I formatting that in string?

Comment: @Fabio: The answer is still the same: Use a *string* to store the phone number, not an integer. That is independent of the language.

Comment: @Martin R if my entity is in Int64, I formatting the into String?

Comment: Again: Use a *String* attribute for the Core Data entity, **not** Int64.

Comment: do not lose patience bro, ok I try.... and excuse me

Comment: The integer 0000009 is the same as just 9, but the phone number 000008 is not the same as 8, you better change the entity to string

Comment: @DanielKrom I try but return this error: libswiftCore.dylib`_swift_runtime_on_report:
->  0x10d372e70 <+0>: pushq  %rbp
    0x10d372e71 <+1>: movq   %rsp, %rbp
    0x10d372e74 <+4>: popq   %rbp
    0x10d372e75 <+5>: retq   
    0x10d372e76 <+6>: nopw   %cs:(%rax,%rax)

Comment: thx to MartinR and DanielKrom...the error depended on an inexplicable cash ... I created a new entity and all is done :)